# Forward mail using gmail API

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api

Is there any code provided by google to forward mail. because i haven't found one. If there is any way to forward mail using GMAIL API with extra content to send with original message. Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see any specific `forward` operation...

You'll have to:

1. [`get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) the message,
2. add your extra content to the top of the original message and
3. change the `to` address, then
4. remove any `cc` and `bcc` addresses [Per @martin-paucot notes from his actual experience doing this]
5. [`send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) it.

Not much help to you but take note of the [Threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads).

Comment: I have extracted multiparts from message and added new multipart in it with new content and now when i send the message it only shows new Content but message contains parts of previous message also can u tell me why ? and what is the solution of this?

Comment: Well that's a different question: you don't want to add a new multipart part to the message, just prepend some text to the existing message.  You would do well to invest some more time researching the format of email messages.

Comment: yes, i can prepend  the text to existing message but if ihave to add new attachments to the same message then?

Comment: Then modify the message to include the attachment(s).

Comment: @john - I have similar requirement. How did you solve it? Please share the references.

Comment: Any updates? It would be great to use the "forward all" option through the API

Answer (score 7):

Watch out while doing this procedure !

I used the answer of Jhon Mee to forward all emails from a user to an other one.
If you just change the "To:" it will continue to send the emails to everyone in "Cc:" and "Bcc:"

Here is the procedure:

1. Retreive the email in raw format
2. Decode the email from base64
3. Replace the line "To:" with the email you want to forward to
4. Remove the lines "CC:" and "Bcc:"
5. Send it

Comment: Why do we remove Cc and Bcc when I want to give option to add Cc and Bcc? Is there any specific instructions to forward? Like in the case of replies, we had "In-Reply-To", "References" header and "Subject" should be the same as well with `Re: ` at start? I tried to use the same format for forwarding and changed the subject to `Fwd: ` but it doesn't work right.

Comment: Basically, forwarding is just sending the same email to an other address. But if you do not remove the CC: and BCC: it will also be sent to the emails provided in those fields

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, access through IMAP and use a Python library like [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html).

@Google Devs: Why not give us easy forwarding through your "Gmail API"?

Comment: My guess would be that's because they want to sell storage