# Forward email in inbox using gmail api with c#

Tags: c#, email, gmail, gmail-api

Respected All, i have successfully read emails from gmail inbox using gmail api v1, but i want to send/forward email already saved in inbox by using its message id (MessageId i get from the list of emails read from inbox). Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward mail using gmail API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995341/forward-mail-using-gmail-api)

Comment: i chkd it, bt unable to get how to do it..... :-)