# Get message and then send to another email using Gmail API with Python

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm following the advice on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995341/forward-mail-using-gmail-api) to set up bulk forwarding using Python. I'm trying to search for messages in the inbox with specific keywords, get the message IDs of those messages, and send those messages to a different person.

The search and getting IDs part works fine. Here's the code:

```py
def search_message(service, user_id, search_string):
    # initiate the list for returning
    list_ids = []

    # get the id of all messages that are in the search string
    search_ids = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=search_string).execute()

    # if there were no results, print warning and return empty string
    try:
        ids = search_ids['messages']

    except KeyError:
        print("WARNING: the search queried returned 0 results")
        print("returning an empty string")
        return ""

    if len(ids)>1:
        for msg_id in ids:
            list_ids.append(msg_id['id'])
        return(list_ids)

    else:
        list_ids.append(ids['id'])
        return list_ids
```

It's when I try to send a message that things get hairy. I'm testing this on a single message ID at the moment, and here's what I've tried:

```py
message_raw = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,format='raw').execute()
message_full = service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=msg_id, format="full", metadataHeaders=None).execute()

## get the subject line
msg_header = message_full['payload']['headers']

# this is a little faster then a loop
subj = [i['value'] for i in msg_header if i["name"]=="Subject"]
subject = subj[0] 

msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message_raw['raw'].encode('UTF-8'))
msg_bytes = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)

# get content type for msg
content_type = msg_bytes.get_content_maintype()

if content_type == 'multipart':
    # there will usually be 2 parts: the first will be the body as a raw string,
    # the second will be the body as html
    parts = msg_bytes.get_payload()

    # return the encoded text
    send_string = parts[0].get_payload()

    # force utf-8 encoding on the string
    send_string = send_string.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')

# now that we have the body in raw string, we will build a new mime object and
# send it via gmail
final_message = MIMEText(send_string)

# set send-to and subject line in the msg
final_message['to'] = to
final_message['subject'] = subject
final_message['from'] = 'tradethenewsapi@gmail.com'

# turn back into raw format and return
raw = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(final_message.as_bytes())
body = {'raw': raw}
```

However, when I go to send the actual email (as [this thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/93) suggests),

```py
message_sent = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body).execute())
```

I keep getting this error

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

No matter what I do to `search_string`, it won't work and keeps giving me the unicode error.

Comment: maybe text is not in `UTF-8` but in `Latin1`, `cp1250` (popular in Windows) or other encoding. For example `b'\x89'.decode('cp1250')` gives me `‰` - per mille sign. Wikipedia: [Per mille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_mille)

Comment: @furas I've tried 10 different encodings so far, nothing works

Comment: error shows problem with code `0x89` which exists in `cp1250` so you should start with this encoding. And some messages can use `cp1250`, other `utf-8` and other different encoding so you can't use one encoding for all messages. You should use `try/except with different encodings till you get result. And if you don't get result then you should print this message to check it directly in Gmail - maybe it can show what ending it uses.

Comment: you use UTF-8 in different places so you should show full error message to see which one makes problem. always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.